# Headless (NextJS) Component not working when added to Sitecore XM cloud Page Designs

Tags: jss, nextjs, xm-cloud

We are facing issue with the few our Headless component created in NextJS for Sitecore XM cloud implementation where nested component is created which ultimately render some code like below.

```
      return (
    <>
      <Image
        srcSet={!sitecoreContext.pageEditing ? somecondition : undefined}
        sizes={!sitecoreContext.pageEditing ? somecondition : undefined}
        field={fields.image?.data}
        className="sample-class"
      />
      {sitecoreContext?.pageEditing ? (
        <Link field={fields.link?.data} className="sample-class" />
      ) : (
        <Text
          field={{ value: fields.link?.data?.value?.text }}
          className="sample-class"
        />
      )}
      <RichText field={fields.text?.data} className="sample class" />
    </>
  );
```

Now whenever we add those components to partial design and then ultimately add that to the Page design then those simply doesn't work when it comes to editing, like we are even not allowed to click on it. This happens when we attach the page design to page and then use XM cloud Page editor to edit the content. The only difference between the components which are working that they are made like container for other components where we have a placeholder to add which ultimately allows editing.

***Note: The components are working fine if we use them directly on pages.***

Let me know if I need add more details to this as I can share only general information for now.

Comment: for me looks like is a similar issue

Comment: @VladIobagiu this site is pure Sitecore XM cloud with no JSS tenant so the solution of changing configuration won't work for us. One more thing there are only certain components which are not working rest everything is fine.

Comment: are the components which doesn't appear on the same placeholder ?

Comment: they appear correctly they are simply not editable at all and community here tagging to close this question by comparing to the other question also not solution for us.

Comment: The other post gives you the reason for this. This is by design in the product. You can't edit a data sourced component that has been added to a partial design anywhere except for on the partial design. If you edit a page that uses that partial design, the fields will be read only. That is by design.